# parent of multi Module spring project with spring cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud

I've looked for answer for quite some time but had no luck so I decided to post it.
Recently I tried to make some simple app with parent pom to easly manage my dependencies version. So I added dependecy  to my parent pom added first simple dependecies and I came up with:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>it.orestes</groupId>
    <artifactId>Landlord</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>discovery</module>
        <module>property</module>
        <module>gateway</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <springboot.version>2.5.2</springboot.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then I made first child project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>it.orestes</groupId>
        <artifactId>Landlord</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>it.orestes.landlord</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>discovery</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And I did tried to build but I ended up with

```
'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server:jar is missing. @ line 18, column 21
```

And now I cannot figure out why spring-boot-dependencies are picked up properly but spring-cloud  not
if I add dependencymanagement to child project its working just fine but it is not something that I aimed for and it started to bother me why its not inherited from parent pom  dependencyManagement?
Is there any way to achive it the way I planned with parent pom or just I can pass property with version to child pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the *spring-cloud-version* from the parent into the child (gateway) module.
Afterall, not all your children modules are going to be gateways so not all have to inherit the *spring-cloud-version* property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>it.orestes</groupId>
    <artifactId>Landlord</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>it.orestes.landlord</groupId>
<artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>discovery</name>

<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```